# project running on live web server but not in local server

Tags: php, localhost

My Project is running in the web server i.e. [Ecommerce Project](http://sandy92.5gbfree.com)
but it is not running in my local server and giving a error i.e.

```
Warning: require_once(Core.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\shop\inc\autoload.php on line 7 
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Core.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\shop\inc\autoload.php on line 7
```

here is my

**index.php**

```
<?php
require_once('inc/autoload.php');
$core = new Core();
$core->run();
?>
```

**Core.php**

```
<?php
class Core {

    public function run() {
        ob_start();
        require_once(Url::getPage());
        ob_get_flush();
    }

}
```

**autoload.php**

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');

function __autoload($class_name) {
    $class = explode("_", $class_name);
    $path = implode("/", $class).".php";
    require_once($path);
}

config.php
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}

// site domain name with http
defined("SITE_URL")
    || define("SITE_URL", "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);

// directory separator
defined("DS")
    || define("DS", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

// root path
defined("ROOT_PATH")
    || define("ROOT_PATH", realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . DS."..".DS));

// classes folder
defined("CLASSES_DIR")
    || define("CLASSES_DIR", "classes");

// pages directory
defined("PAGES_DIR")
    || define("PAGES_DIR", "pages");

// modules folder
defined("MOD_DIR")
    || define("MOD_DIR", "mod");

// inc folder
defined("INC_DIR")
    || define("INC_DIR", "inc");

// templates folder
defined("TEMPLATE_DIR")
    || define("TEMPLATE_DIR", "template");

// emails path
defined("EMAILS_PATH")
    || define("EMAILS_PATH", ROOT_PATH.DS."emails");

// catalogue images path
defined("CATALOGUE_PATH")
    || define("CATALOGUE_PATH", ROOT_PATH.DS."media".DS."catalogue");

// add all above directories to the include path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(ROOT_PATH.DS.CLASSES_DIR),
    realpath(ROOT_PATH.DS.PAGES_DIR),
    realpath(ROOT_PATH.DS.MOD_DIR),
    realpath(ROOT_PATH.DS.INC_DIR),
    realpath(ROOT_PATH.DS.TEMPLATE_DIR),
    get_include_path()
)));
```

Comment: Did you actually read the error message? Do the words `No such file or directory` mean anything to you?

Comment: but it is running in the live server but whenever i try it on the local server it display this errors

Answer (score 0):

You seems to be missing PEAR. Has been a while but isn't that a separate module in php?

Answer (score 0):

Change the path here...

```
require_once('config.php');
```